# How do you post an array of textboxes (containing commas) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a list of addresses from a form to a controller

```
<input type="text" name="address" value="sample1, sample1">
<input type="text" name="address" value="sample2, sample2">
```

But this creates a problem since I get four values for address i.e. sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4 there is no difference between the values for the 1st and 2nd address.

What would be the best way to achieve this in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of the controls?

```
<input type="text" name="address1" value="sample1, sample1">
<input type="text" name="address2" value="sample2, sample2">
```

Comment: If you make that address[0] and address[1] they will post into an array "string[] address" in the model automatically. Still need to String.Split(',') the commas though.

Comment: Yes tried that but the problem is if the array is not contiguous i.e. 0, 1, 2 (I use jQuery to allow deletion of elements). I get only 1 address and all others get dropped out.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm considering is having jQuery replace all comma's in the inputs to something like ~@~ then after it is posted and split, I convert the ~@~ back to comma's.  Pretty lame.  PHP has figured this out, why can't Microsoft?  If there was a way to choose the delimiter, that would be nice too.